# Using Facebook SDK in xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am having a problem integrating the Facebook SDK in my xCode project. I downloaded the frameworks with cocoapods, and they show up in the workspace. However, I am having trouble because the instructions on Facebook are in Objective-C, and I am trying to use Swift. I have pasted the code into a site that translates, but I am still having trouble. I keep getting an error whenever I try putting in the code because xCode can't detect the frameworks it seems. I really need to do this for an assignment at work, and no one seems to be able to help. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

There are few steps that you have to follow:

1) in your app delegate, did finish launching you need to add this code:

```
PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```

2) You should also add the following  function to app delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
                openURL: url,
                sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                annotation: annotation)
}
```

3) in your applicationdidbecomeactive, add the following code

```
FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
```

4) MAKE SURE YOU USE THE FOLLOWING FRAMEWORKS:

```
PARSEFACEBOOKUTILSV4.framework
FBSDKCOREKIT.framework
FBSDKLOGINKIT.framework
BOLTS.framework
```

some of the frameworks are outdated, just use the following for now and it should get you going, make sure you dont have unnecessary frameworks that can cause problems.

Comment: Thank you! Is this in addition to the instructions on Facebook, or are these steps the only things I need to use Facebook